# Passing data to child container view

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicontainerview

I want to pass string data from parent vc to child vc in swift 3.
My child vc is container view. So watch my code:

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController
@IBOutlet var continerView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildVCID") as! ChildViewController!
        vc?.myStr = "Hello Bro"
        addChildViewController(vc!)
        continerView.addSubview((vc?.view)!)
        didMove(toParentViewController: vc)
}
}
```

And my child code is:

```
class ChildViewController: UIViewController
 var myStr:String!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("Str is: ",myStr)
    }
```

So this error will show:
[image]

Therefore how to fix this?

Comment: can you attach your project

Comment: please go step by step, like just dont pass data directly, try first to load view(add subview). If its successful , then pass data, try modification in code  var myStr:String! to var myStr:String?. I am sure your code is correct , only you are missing something with optionals.

Comment: Please format your code properly. At least check that it's properly set up. There are a lot of issues I can identify. Neither of classes has an opening bracket, call to super.viewDidAppear not there, code alignment, spaces between functions, force unwrapping is evil... etc

Comment: @OlegDanu correct bro. Its just optional binding where he messed.  i tried piece of code from ChildViewController,  change  var myStr:String! to  var myStr:String? , your app will not crash.

Comment: I suggest adding `super.viewDidAppear(animated)` as the first line of ChildViewController viewDidAppear. I don't think this is causing the crash though.

Comment: I tried same code to replicate the issue, but it worked fine.

Comment: Try adding super.viewDidAppear(animated) in childVCs viewDidAppear, ass suggested by @MobileDan

Comment: I think `didMove(toParentViewController: vc)` should be `didMove(toParentViewController: self)`

Answer (score 3):

This code incorporates suggestions made in comments and does not use force unwrapping.

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var continerView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let childViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildVCID") as? ChildViewController else {
            print("Creating ViewController from ChildVCID failed")
            return
        }

        childViewController.myStr = "Hello Bro!"
        addChildViewController(childViewController)
        continerView.addSubview(childViewController.view)
        didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    }
}

class ChildViewController: UIViewController {
    var myStr:String?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("Str is: ", myStr ?? "(nil)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is written in question is correct, all are just missing one main thing where storyboards comes in focus, as ChildViewController in storyboard is already **embeded in ContainerView with embed seague**, which automatically loads this vc to container, and app crashed beacause 'myStr' **was force unwrapped while is nil**,

I have written ParentViewController, minimal '!' & '?', why to use them while they are unnecessary.

```
 class ParentViewController: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet var cv: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "idChildViewController") as! ChildViewController
     vc.myStr = "Hello Bro"
     addChildViewController(vc)
     cv.addSubview(vc.view)
     didMove(toParentViewController: vc)
    }
   }
 }
```

Now, in ChildViewController, why to declare varible as not optional,

```
  class ChildViewController: UIViewController
   var myStr:String?  // or var myStr = "" //best way to declare string 
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
   }
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      print("Str is: ",myStr)
   }
```

Run the app, will give console output twice as ,

Str is:  nil  //loaded from storyboard

Str is:  Optional("Hello Bro") // loaded from parent